# Survival analysis: Use of "legible" metrics like RMSE

Tags: survival, predictive-models, metric, lifelines

I apply a Cox proportional hazards model to some machine failure data and I want to know, "how good" my model is. Metrics like RMSE or MAE are said to be not suitable for this kind of model, "because the difference between a censored value and the predicted value could be due to poor prediction or due to censoring" (https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#model-selection-and-calibration-in-survival-regression).

I wonder if it's still possible to use such metrics in one or the other way: If, for example, I remove all censored observations from my validation set, set "observed == False" for all remaining observations and predict conditional survival after some time t<T, I could compare predictions and true values by means of metrics like RMSE.
The disadvantage being, I suppose, that I would have to assume that there is no significant difference in terms of survival between censored and non-censored observations.

My question: Is this a suitable approach under the said assumption? Or are there other possibilities of using "legible" metrics like RMSE or MAE for survival analysis? (I contrast such metrics from metrics like AIC or likelihood which are interpretable only in comparison between models).